# How to integrate Live layer effect in QGIS 2.10 with the help of python code based automatation process?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.10

I need to work with live layer effect (blur, outer glow, shadow) etc . I know how to use this with the help of QGIS symbol tool. But i need to integrate this in to my python automated map generation process. I am searching code for this but unable to find out. If anyone knows it then please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `QgsPaintEffect`. It's the base class from which all the live layer effects inherit:

https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPaintEffect.html

`QgsSymbolLayerV2.setPaintEffect()` is probably what you need:

https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbolLayerV2.html#a5d4f3921ee369094736f17ec44361620